# How to map a function result to a list if the function is async?

Tags: javascript, storybook

Javascript newbie here. I saw this: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/overview

```
// .storybook/main.js

function findStories() {
  // your custom logic returns a list of files
}

module.exports = {
  stories: async (list) => [...list, ...findStories()],
};
```

And I'm assuming the `[...list, ...findStories()]` maps an array result from `findStories()` into list, but how would I get it to work if `findStories()` was an async function and I needed to await the Promise that `findStories()` returned? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will await on `findStories()` and once you have output, then you can concat using `spread syntax`. Like this `async (list) => {
    const stories = await findStories();
    return [...list, ...stories]
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `findStories` be an async function you can do it like this:

```
module.exports = {
  stories: async (list) => [...list, ...(await findStories())],
};
```